# Coordinate ring of Grassmannian is UFD

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Hy guys. I'm trying to understand this proof, taken from this [blog](https://levjake.wordpress.com/2014/07/09/schubert-calculus-i-geometry-of-gkn/).

[image]

The last part of the proof is not clear to me. More precisely,  I don't understand why the subgroup of elements fixing the factors is closed and has finite  index.

**NOTE**: I need understanding this proof for trying to show the same proposition for any alg. closed field.

Comment: Consider the entrywise action of the group $\operatorname{SL}_k$ on $k$-tuples of polynomials. Let $G$ be the stabilizer of the $k$-tuple $\left(f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_k\right)$. Then, the orbit-stabilizer theorem shows $G$-set $\operatorname{SL}_k / G$ is isomorphic to the $\operatorname{SL}_k$-orbit of the $k$-tuple $\left(f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_k\right)$. Thus, the former $G$-set is finite (since the latter orbit is). In other words, the subgroup $G$ has finite index in $\operatorname{SL}_k$. Why is it closed? Well, it's a polynomial condition.

Comment: Thanks :) Do you mean that the finitness of the index is a closed condition in the Zariski topology?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: I immagine that $SL_n$ is also a connected topological group in the Zariski topology, right?

Comment: PS: You have correcty answered my question. Post the comment as answer, please :)

Comment: Actually, I'm no longer sure about my comment. I've missed the "(and possibly introducing scalars)" part. If the action of $\operatorname{SL}_k$ can introduce scalars, then how do we know that the orbit is finite? We need to use something else about $\operatorname{SL}_k$; some sort of semisimplicity?

Comment: Maybe passing to the projectivization of $\mathbb{C}[x_{11},\ldots,x_{k,n}]$?